# Programmatically add opacity to a color in Typescript

Tags: typescript, colors, opacity, alpha

I have been trying to find a way to add opacity to a color and retrieve the HEX code of the resultant color in Typescript.

Is it possible in Typescript to do something like: Color('#A25297').alpha(0.65)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, if you program it, it is ...

```
function addAlpha(color: string, opacity: number): string {
    // coerce values so ti is between 0 and 1.
    const _opacity = Math.round(Math.min(Math.max(opacity || 1, 0), 1) * 255);
    return color + _opacity.toString(16).toUpperCase();
}
addAlpha('FF0000', 1); // returns 'FF0000FF'
addAlpha('FF0000', 0.5); // returns 'FF000080'
```

Of course, you can improve this function by checking that `color` has the proper format, by using regular expressions.

Comment: Solved the purpose. Thanks!

Comment: The opacity isn't padded properly for low values which causes unexpected colours, I had to alter the opacity calculation to pad a zero: 
```('0' + _opacity.toString(16)).slice(-2).toUpperCase()```

Comment: This doesn't work if you hex has already opacity inside it . For example : `#63B50BD1`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [color](https://www.npmjs.com/package/color) library for the operation you seek. It has the type definitions to use it comfortably from within typescript.

Installation:

```
npm i color
npm i @types/color
```

Usage:

```
let Color = require('color');
let cmyColor = Color('#A25297').alpha(0.65);
let colorAsHex = cmyColor.hex();
```

... which is, coincidentally, exactly the syntax you were proposing.

#### Edit:

After actually trying my proposed solution, it became clear that the result will not work as intended. The returned hex value does not respect the change in alpha. It will however, after the lib has resolved [this issue](https://github.com/Qix-/color/issues/32) to include the 8-letter hex notation.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It looks like a better solution in the long run but I could not get it work. I must be missing something. When I tried this code, an error: "Cannot find name 'Color'" was thrown. To fix this, I added an "import { Color } from 'color'" which resulted in another error: "Module '"node_modules/@types/color/index"' has no exported member 'Color'".

Comment: Your problem is the result of a missing ES6 import (The color lib still an older method for imports).